# When creating an instance on google cloud engine, `Permission denied on 'locations/asia-northeast3-a'` error occurs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

An error "Permission denied on 'locations/asia-northeast3-a' (or it may not exist)" occurs when I tried to create an google cloud engine instance from the GCP WebUI.

The problematic `asia-northeast3` region and zones do exist.

```
$ gcloud compute regions list --filter asia-northeast3
NAME             CPUS  DISKS_GB  ADDRESSES  RESERVED_ADDRESSES  STATUS  TURNDOWN_DATE
asia-northeast3  0/24  0/4096    0/8        0/8                 UP
```

```
$ gcloud compute zones list --filter asia-northeast3
NAME               REGION           STATUS  NEXT_MAINTENANCE  TURNDOWN_DATE
asia-northeast3-a  asia-northeast3  UP
asia-northeast3-b  asia-northeast3  UP
asia-northeast3-c  asia-northeast3  UP
```

I've checked this [url](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations) and it shows `asia-northeast3` is up and running.

The error message says "Permission denied" on the location, but doesn't give any detailed explanation. As I could not find any permissions regarding this issue, I would be grateful if anyone can put a finger on where I should look into.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by changing a billing currency to KRW. I didn't think that the type of currency can be source of the problem. But it turns out that asia-northeast3(Seoul) region force users to pay only in KRW.

Comment: Yeah, after countless hours spent on this permission bug, I found it's related to billing. My country currency is INR and I can't be able to deploy any service to asia-south1 (mumbai) and asia-south2 (delhi) region. So, I created a new billing account with INR as currency and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the error is more intuitive than in your case about currency perhaps.

In my case, I simply had a spelling mistake in the region, I used something like `asia-northeast-3` instead of `asia-northeast3`, causing

> ```sh
> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok],
> message=[Permission denied on 'locations/asia-northeast-3' (or it may
> not exist)]
> ```

Resulting code:

```
REGION=asia-northeast3
gcloud functions call vc_feedout --region=${REGION}
```

*Side-note: Generally, also check that the region that you choose for gcloud is the same as the region that is in the "Details" tab of your Cloud Function, but this divergence in regions would cause another error than the one in the question.*

Comment: thank you. exactly what happened to me

Answer (score 1):

I had a missing argument in my Cloud function deploy command: `gcloud functions deploy <name> --gen2`

Comment: Bro you saved me some valuable time. Thanks!